# Convert cURL to Python - Upload A File

Tags: python, curl, linkedin-api

I can't seem to convert cURL to python. From the docs:

```
curl -i --upload-file ~/Desktop/Myimage.jpg -H 'Authorization: Bearer Redacted' "https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQLKRJOn_yNw6wAAAW2T0DWnRStny4dzsNVJjlF3aN4-H3ZR9Div77kKoQ&app=1983914&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1Dnjy796bpjEY1
```

I have tried using files instead of data to no avail.

The current code below creates the proper response 201, but it's blank (has no JSON details with an image to use for future API calls). Let me what changes I need to make to upload a file via a PUT request without using a multi-part form (ie "files=")

```
uploadUrl = data["value"]["uploadMechanism"]["com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest"]["uploadUrl"]

filename = "ffadfads.jpeg"
media_url = "https://1000logos.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/LinkedIn-Logo.png"
request = requests.get(media_url, stream=True)
if request.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as image:
        for chunk in request:
            image.write(chunk)
    #files = {'fileupload': open(filename)}
    files = {"fileupload":(filename,open(filename,"rb"),'application-type')}
    image_headers = {
        'Accept': 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + real_token
    }
    response = requests.request("PUT", uploadUrl, data=open(filename,"rb"), headers=image_headers)
    print response
    print response.text
    print response.json()
```

Comment: try this https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: @bharatk, that was the first place I went to and doesn't help

Comment: Why do you have the `Accept` header set to `image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif`? You would think it should be set to `application/json` if you are expecting JSON from the server. What are the headers, including cookies, of the request when performed by your browser?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay I tried tweaking different things for Accept header (the image/jpeg was the most recent one).  None of the tweaks worked.  The header is fine, I get a 201 response.  LinkedIn is weird.  You used to upload via form which worked well, now this new way is stumping me because of how the cURL converts to python.

Comment: Have you tried using cURL to know that it works? (I assume it won't work) I was just reading [Rich Media Shares - LinkedIn | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares), and if I'm reading it correctly, you first need to make a POST request to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload` with the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json` along with a JSON payload. The server will then respond with JSON which has a `uploadUrl` key, the value of which you then use to actually upload the image.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay that's where the "uploadUrl" value comes from in the request above.

Comment: Did you try using cURL with the `uploadUrl` value that comes from a POST request to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload`? Or try doing it all with cURL, just to make sure it works as documented.

Comment: I'm using the uploadUrl value from the POST request to /assets?action=registerUpload. I trust their documentation is correct and the cURL will work. Just need help converting to python.

Comment: have you tried other libs instead of requests ? Maybe pycurl (http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#file-upload-put)?

Comment: You problem isn't converting curl to python...
What you need to do is re-write this code, there are a LOT of errors.
`for chunk in request`?! the `request` is something already sent, also it is not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to confuse a request with a response.

```py
response1 = requests.get(media_url, stream=True)
if response1.status_code == 200:
    response2 = requests.request("PUT", uploadUrl,
                                 data=response1.iter_content(),
                                 headers=image_headers)
```

Comment: changing variable names doesn't affect the output.

Comment: True, but it does make the code a lot easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to use the requests library, you could try running the curl command directly from python, using [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and [shlex.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) for Python 3.

Using the example curl command from your question (adding a missing double quote at the end) the following code would run it and capture the response as text.

```
import shlex
import subprocess

curl_command_line = '''curl -i --upload-file ~/Desktop/Myimage.jpg \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer Redacted' \
"https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQLKRJOn_yNw6wAAAW2T0DWnRStny4dzsNVJjlF3aN4-H3ZR9Div77kKoQ&app=1983914&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1Dnjy796bpjEY1"'''

args = shlex.split(curl_command_line)
response = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
```

For Python 2.7, replace the last line with:

```
response = subprocess.call(args)
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.7; tried converting and this didn't work :/

Comment: In Python 2.7 there is no run() function, but you could use call() instead. I have edited my answer to include both python versions.

Comment: Whether I use cURL or python, I can a 201 message but it doesn't actually post to LinkedIn.  Their API is the worst.  No code snippets.  No example responses.  Just a cURL example.

Comment: To provide more clarity, I get a 201 (created) response but it's blank.  It doesn't show the post details and it doesn't post to LinkedIn

Comment: A 201 response, even with a blank body, should still be a successful upload. Have you tried the [Retrieve Shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#retrieve-shares) steps to see if you can access your upload?

Comment: If you can provide a python snippet, I'll send you $40 via PayPal

Comment: Based on the documentation, you should make a GET request to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/{share ID}` where {share ID} is the last part of the value.asset key from the json response to the registerUpload request. In the sample response this would be C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ. Adapt the following curl command using your access token and image id: `curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer Redacted' "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares/C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ"`. If this works, you can then run the curl command in python as I mention in my answer.

Comment: I don't have access to pull images from Shares.  If it doesn't show on the page, the Share's wont display anything.  I'm moreso offer $40 for python snippet on how to upload image to LinkedIn.  Can do a clean $50 for you.

Comment: You can [Check Status of Upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#check-status-of-upload). Adapting and running the following curl command should return a json with the asset (image in your case) details. This should confirm that your upload was successful.  
`curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer Redacted' "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ"`

Comment: I've tried. Don't have permissions to access Shares

Comment: Have you noticed that my last comment pertains to assets and not shares? It is mentioned as the third step in [How to Upload Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#how-to-upload-images) with the Assets API.